# How do I use the backdropClick of a mat-dialog to close the dialog and send the data that changed back to parent component

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have the following scenario:
I am using a mat-dialog to display information of a *ngFor card, in this card there are a couple of information that is static, like the body of a message, title and the person who published it, but I also have dynamic elements, in this case a like button.

When someone click on the like button outside the dialog (which is a expanded view of a publication) the like button turns red and it's counter receive a value of it + 1, if the person clicks on it again it turns gray and have de value of it - 1.

If someone open the dialog and click on the button and click on the close button, it works fine, but if someone clicks on the like button and then click on the backdrop or press "esc" the data is not sent back to the parent component.

My code is as follows:

```
visualize(value: any) { //method that opens the dialog

    if (value.link && !value.video_destaque)
        window.open(value.link, "_blank");
    else {
        const publicationData = { //pass the data to dialog
            id: value.id,
            cabecalho: value.header,
            corpo: value.body,
            ...
            curtiu: value.curtiu,
            classeFavorite: value.classeFavorite,
            num_curtidas: value.num_curtidas,
        };

        const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(VisualizePublicationComponent, { //open dialog
            maxHeight: '85vh',
            width: '70vh',
            panelClass: 'custom-dialog-container',
            disableClose: true,
            data: {
                publicacao: publicationData
            }
        });

        dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => { 
            this.post.curtiu = result.curtiu;
            this.post.favoritou = result.favoritou;
            this.post.num_curtidas = result.num_curtidas;
            this.post.classeLike = result.classeLike;
            this.post.classeFavorite = result.classeFavorite;
        });
    }
}
```

the last part "dialogRef.afterClosed..." passes data back to parent component, but it only works with the mat-dialog-close button, it seems that if you click outside of the dialog it thinks that you want to cancel and completely forget the data.

as it is a like button the user probably wants to read the post, and then like it and close it the easiest way (clicking outside of box).

I think the answer to my problem is related with the following code

```
dialogRef.backdropClick().subscribe(() => {
    dialogRef.close();
})
```

but I don't know what I am missing.

Answer (score 9):

Try to add this

### VisualizePublicationComponent

```
...
constructor(public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<VisualizePublicationComponent>) {  }
...

ngOnInit() {
   this.dialogRef.beforeClose().subscribe(() => this.dialogRef.close(this.resultData));
}
...
```

Where **this.resultData** is the data that you want to return to the parent component. I've tried that and it works for esc and backdrop click.
Hope that helps.

Comment: Do we need to unsubscribe the subscription also?

Answer (score 2):

As a matter of material design, clicking outside the dialog is the same as pressing escape and both are equivalent to a cancel operation, therefore no data change should occur. Users would not expect changes to be 'pushed' if they cancel their changes.

That being said, if you want to access the dialog's copy of the data (not the 'result' from a proper 'close'), you can use `dialogRef.componentInstance.data`:

```
dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => { 

    if (!result) {
        result = dialogRef.componentInstance.data;
    }

    this.post.curtiu = result.curtiu;
    this.post.favoritou = result.favoritou;
    this.post.num_curtidas = result.num_curtidas;
    this.post.classeLike = result.classeLike;
    this.post.classeFavorite = result.classeFavorite;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer was a little different then what I expected, my coworker helped me out with it, I already had a function that would make the control of the like button, it changed the color of the button and added 1 to the counter etc., what I needed to to was in that same function call a method inside a service that would make a http request to change everything, the logic behind the like button is now made in the model, so when the http request look for the data it return a model that already return the correct output, this method is better because it updates the view immediately for both the dialog and the parent component.

I still believe that there is a way to do the same thing with mat-dialog propriets, but is not really necessary.

here is the function that I mentioned:

```
public likeControl(publicacao: Publicacao) {
    const resultadoCurtir = publicacao.curtir();

    if (resultadoCurtir) {
        this.consumerCommunicationService.likePost(this.pessoa, publicacao.id).subscribe(
            response => {
                if (response.status < 299) {
                    PostCardComponent.successMessageToast('Pronto!');
                } else {
                    const promise = PostCardComponent.errorMessageFromResponse(response);
                }
            }
        );
    } else {
        this.consumerCommunicationService.dislikePost(this.pessoa, publicacao.id).subscribe(
            response => {
                if (response.status < 299) {
                    PostCardComponent.successMessageToast('Pronto!');
                } else {
                    const promise = PostCardComponent.errorMessageFromResponse(response);
                }
            }
        );
    }
}
```

here is an example of the service method:

```
public likePost(consumerId, postId): any {
    return this.http.put(environment.baseUrl + '/consumidor/' + consumerId + '/mensagens/mensagem/' + postId + '/curtir', {},
        {observe: 'response'})
        .pipe(
            tap((response: any) => console.debug(JSON.stringify(response))),
            catchError(this.handleError('likePost(' + consumerId + ', ' + postId + ')', []))
        );

}
```

this is incomplete, there istill a bunch of functions in there, but that is the main idea, this way my code works better then I actully intended and I keep it in good practices and following the architecture that we are implementing, thanks for your answers.

Comment: It isn't clear how your `likeControl` and `likePost` functions are used with the dialog. Since this is the answer to your problem, readers might find it useful to know how those functions solve your problem. It shouldn't be necessary to make a request to 'change everything' when 'everything' is already local.

Comment: likeControl is a function that the like button calls when it is clicked, likePost is a function inside a service to communicate with the backend, everthing is not local, that info is saved in an external db